# Capybara - Poltergeist and Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I'm using Cucumber to run tests and I use both PhantomJS (poltergeist) and Selenium WebDriver. One of my tests is following a redirect to a new window from a hyperlink.

Is there a way that I can write into my step definition for navigating to a window to say: If using Poltergeist, run this line of code else run this one (Selenium as default)?:

Example:

When in Selenium Browser:

```
within_window(->{ page.title == 'Title' }) do
  expect(current_url).to eq('URL')
  page.driver.browser.close
end
```

When in Poltergeist:

```
new_window = window_opened_by { click_link 'Something' }
within_window new_window do
  # code
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can base your conditional on the value of Capybara.current_driver

```
if Capybara.current_driver == :selenium
   do the selenium things
else
   do the poltergeist things
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've tried but so far had no luck.  it won't enforce the if statement

Comment: What is the vale of Capybara.current_driver at that point in your code, or page.mode?

Comment: It was at page.mode.  When running in Poltergeist it was still trying to run the selenium code.  I'm trying a different approach in that I tag the test @javascript and set my capybara.javascript_driver =:chrome but it runs the browser in Firefox so not having much luck there either.

Comment: I've done it, turns out my code structure was incorrect.  I implemented it by:

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working, turns out that I wasn't implementing the code for Poltergeist properly.  My code is:

```
if Capybara.default_driver == :selenium
  within_window(->{ page.title == 'TITLE' }) do
    expect(current_url).to eq('URL')
    page.driver.browser.close
  end
else
  sleep 1
  new_window = page.driver.browser.window_handles.last
  within_window new_window do
    expect(current_url).to eq('URL')
  end
end
```

Thank you very much Tom Walpole, your help was much appreciated